# How to extend the view out of drawer layout?

Tags: android, view, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

[image]

I need to add a `View` over the drawer layout like showing on this picture. How this can be done? I need to show the red portion always on app in every screen.

Comment: Using the `android:translationX` attribute might worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **Frame Layout** as a parent ViewGroup and implement the Drawer Layout inside the Frame Layout